# Should I bind JDBC connection to servlet thread?

Tags: servlets, jdbc, connection-pooling

I'm using jndi to access to dbcp datasource.

In scope of one servlet request each time call `static_dataSource.getConnection()` returns new connection.

In hibernate there is a function `getCurrentSession()`. As far as I understand this function return connection that binded to current thread. Should I bind my jdbc connection to thread also?

My goal is call complex business logic in scope of one transaction that contains many DAO calls, per one http request. Like in Spring I can annotate whole service class with @Transactional.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you not bind a JDBC connection to a thread.  Use a connection pool and hang onto the connection for the shortest time possible: acquire from pool, perform operation, close the connection, return to pool.

Your persistence code ought to be completely separate from the web tier.  You should be able to test and use it independent of the web tier.  Anything that you do to tie the two together will diminish the effectiveness of the persistence tier.

Comment: But what I want is to call complex business logic in scope of one transaction that contains many DAO calls. Like in Spring I can annotate whole service class with @Transactional.

Comment: So why aren't you using Spring?  The ideas should translate over - let the object that owns the use case/transaction and all the DAOs required for the business logic obtain the connection and make it available to all the DAOs that need it.  Then they close it and return it to the pool.  One connection per thread won't scale very well.